# PYTHON try-except: Trick to avoid tabulating?

Tags: python, exception

In other languages like Javascript, C++, .. I got used to not indent try-catch block since it makes the code easier to read for me (indenting/tabulating gives the false impression that the code is executed if some condition applies, which is false), so I write code with next style:

```
...
        try{
"normal code flow"
"normal code flow"
...
        }catch(...){
    "indented abnormal exception condition"
    ...
        }
```

I've been trying to figure out how it could be possible to do something similar in Python, but looks like the syntax always force tabulating the "normal code flow". I wonder if someone knows of a trick to avoid it.

Comment: "gives the false impression that the code is executed if some condition applies" well, that is in fact the case: The code in the `try` block is executed unless an exception is thrown. By your own interpretation, indentation makes perfect sense here. Also, get rid of that interpretation, as it does e.g. not apply to `with`.

Comment: Notice that the semantic of try-except can be interpreted like "if not exception execute code1 else execute code2" but it's actually different since the exception can be raised anywhere in code1 and so part of code1 and code2 will be executed in unpredicted ways. This is one of the reasons why I don't like to use try-catch as normal if-then-else blocks. Also I don't want my error-control code to disturb (indent) the normal code flow.

Comment: You are right. But that does not mean that it is wrong to indent code in a try block, but just that your assumption / interpretation that indented blocks imply "conditional" execution is wrong. What about indentation after `class`, `def`, or `with`? A `for` loop isn't conditional either.

Comment: Particularly if you are working together with other developers, it is _critical_ to obey coding conventions, whether they are mandatory, as in Python, or not, as in C/Java. And once you do so, the indentation will not bother you anymore, but help to quickly identify try/catch blocks (and others).

Comment: @ tobias_k : class, def, with, for, ... are all related to variable scope semantics, while try-except is related to non-defined/non-deterministic/asynchronous exception control. It's a different "beast" much more complex. Going down the bare metal for example in assembler exceptions are assigned to interrupt vectors. (IMHO I think that the syntax used "surrounding" normal code in Python, C++, Java, ... is just plain wrong. It will be better to define exception control points at function start, as assembler/hardware does).

Comment: Well, now we have another thing that needs indentation: variable scopes. But what about `if` and `while` then? They don't fit this pattern. And try/catch is "more complex", so it needs ... less indentation?   You have a few options: 1) go with the flow; 2) be "that guy" in the dev team whose code others don't want to read or maintain, 3) write a letter to Guido van Rossum and explain to him why Python is doing it wrong, or 4) create your own programming language. If I were you, I'd go with 1.

Answer (score 3):

No, absolutely not. One of the major principles of Python is that indentation is significant. There is no way around this. If you don't want this, you need to find another language.

Comment: Unless you `from __future__ import braces`... huehueheu.

Answer (score 1):

Python followed indentation strictly, see [here](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#code-lay-out), and also look this, [indentation enter link description here
so you have to use like this.

```
 try:
       "normal code flow"
       "normal code flow"
       ...
   except:
       "indented abnormal exception condition"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your answers.

The original question is whether there is a *trick* (unknown syntax feature) to UN-indent code, not whether I have to use or leave Python apart if I don't like it.

Looks anyway that the answer is NO. NO such trick exists and nothing will be supported in a future. Ikaros45 comment gives the answer:

```
>>> from __future__ import braces
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: not a chance
```